# Global vs local variables?

Tags: ruby, methods, factorial

I am wondering why my code works in one instance but doesn't in another. Does it have something to do with local and global variables?

This works:

```
def factorial num
  result = 1
  while (num > 1)
    result = result * num
    num -= 1
  end
  puts result
end
```

This doesn't work:

```
result = 1

def factorial num
  while (num > 1)
    result = result.to_i * num
    num -= 1
  end
  puts result
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything inside of a method definition cannot see local variables from other places. That sounds weird, but here's two ways to fix it:

```
    result = 1
    number = 10

    def factorial(num,result_value)
      while (num > 1)
        result_value = result_value.to_i * num
        num -= 1
      end
      puts result_value
    end

    factorial(number, result)
```

That passes result as an argument. That's a great way of handling the method because it doesn't allow you to change the value of result from within the method. That might not seem like a big deal but "pure methods" like this become very valuable as the size the code increases.

This is the "dirty" or un-pure way of doing the same thing:

```
@result = 1

def factorial(num)
  while (num > 1)
    @result = @result.to_i * num
    num -= 1
  end
  puts @result
end
```

Putting an `@` in front of a variable name allows its scope to expand to methods defined outside of its scope. This becomes a problem as the complexity of your code increases.

Random personal opinion: even though Ruby doesn't require you to put the parentheses next to a method definition, you always should. It makes the code a lot more explicit and easier to read. Follow your heart though ;)

Comment: Ah, thank you. I just assumed that the result was a global variable because it was not defined in any method. But I see that I need to put `@` to make it global. And I will take your suggestion on putting parens next to method definitions. I used to put parens, but I didn't see anyone doing it, so I dropped them, thinking it was not common practice.

Comment: "Follow your heart though ;)" at least until the programming lead tells you to start doing it in code review.

Comment: @RubyUser `$var` is a global variable. `@var` is called an instance variable. `$var` is visible everywhere but `@var` is not visible everywhere. @amiksch In my opinion, parenthesis makes it harder to read.

Answer (score 0):

You could experiment by prepending all `result`s with a $ sign, making it global. Prepending with a @ results in an instance variable, also interesting. Sidenote: `puts` prints and returns `nil`, so your method returns `nil`.

Comment: I actually tried it with multiple numbers and it works. For example `factorial 5` returns `120`.

Answer (score 0):

```
result = 1 # line 1

def factorial num
  while (num > 1)
    result = result.to_i * num 
    num -= 1
  end
  puts result
end
```

In this code, `factorial` doesn't know about `result` variable from the line 1.
When Ruby find `result = result.to_i * num` in your method it will first assign `nil` to the `result`. Then Ruby will try to run `result.to_i * num`. Since `result` is already `nil`, `result.to_i` is equal 0.

Here is another example:

```
def foo
  a = a
  puts "#{a.class}"
end
foo #NilClass
```

Answer (score 0):

In the *Doesn't Work* version the `result` variable you've assigned to 1 isn't visible inside the `factorial` method.

Now there is a possibly unexpected behaviour in Ruby that if you try to assign a variable and you refer to the same variable on the right hand side of the assignment, if that variable doesn't have a value yet then it is treated as `nil` rather than raising an error. So the first time round the loop when you perform

```
result = result.to_i * num
```

it's equivalent to `result = nil.to_i * num` and `nil.to_i` is equal to 0 so this then sets up `result` to be 0 for subsequent iterations of the loop and as you're just multiplying the value of result stays on 0.

Comment: That's why it didn't work when I didn't use `.to_i`. Because result was treated as `nil`. That makes so much sense, thanks!